# yii2 excel import using arogachev plugin

Tags: excel, import, yii2, yii-extensions

I am importing excel with column name FirstName, LastName and Username. Username is unique in db and model validation both. I am trying to import excel which has 2 row with same username.

It throws below error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'a@2.com' for key 'username'

But this error should not come as before importing excelsheet there is no such value in DB. And model validation should detect duplicate value.

Please help

Comment: please give your controller code

Comment: i think validate `$model->validate()` before `$model->save()` in controller.

Comment: I am validation before saving. Actually the validation are working. When I import the sheet with the record already present in the DB it indeed show me validation error. But it does not work when there are same username row in the excelsheet.

Comment: because you can use `unique` validation in model

Comment: yes so that unique validation should work here also.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there was a bug in basic import with this type of validation because the validation needs to be performed after previous models were saved.

I fixed this and released new version.

Please update to the latest version using command:

```
composer update arogachev/yii2-excel
```